# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' - LSTM multivariate time series forecasting

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm

I am attempting to build an LSTM model to forecast multivariant time series data.

My data looks like this:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize']=20,10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dropout,Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

I have combined date and time to date_time

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
df.index=df['date_time']
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(df["Close"],label='Close Price history')
```

Filtered to date_time and close

```
data=df.sort_index(ascending=True,axis=0)
new_dataset=pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['date_time',"Close"])
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    new_dataset["date_time"][i]=data['date_time'][i]
    new_dataset["Close"][i]=data["Close"][i]
```

Then when I try to normalise the new data set

```
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
final_dataset=new_dataset.values
train_data=final_dataset[0:987,:]
valid_data=final_dataset[987:,:]
new_dataset.index=new_dataset.date_time
new_dataset.drop("date_time",axis=1,inplace=True)
scaler=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data=scaler.fit_transform(final_dataset)
x_train_data,y_train_data=[],[]
for i in range(60,len(train_data)):
    x_train_data.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_train_data.append(scaled_data[i,0])
    
x_train_data,y_train_data=np.array(x_train_data),np.array(y_train_data)
x_train_data=np.reshape(x_train_data,(x_train_data.shape[0],x_train_data.shape[1],1))
```

I get the following error " TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'"

How can i correct this issue? I have read that converting the time to unix format may resolve this, how would I do that?

trying to set float based on date+time

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a float to a string like this:

```
float_to_string=str(the_float)
```